# the code under the map operator do not work on angular 6

Tags: httpclient, angular6

i'm using HttpClient for getting data from my PHP Api for angular
but when i call the `checkYear` method, the code in the map operator don't run (no console log, no data returned).
this is my service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BACKEND_URL } from '../constants';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YearService {
  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  checkYear(year:string)
  {
    return this.http.get(BACKEND_URL + "/annees/getbyname/" + year).pipe(
      map( res => {console.log("from db",res);return res})
    )
  }
}
```

i need a help!!

Comment: How do you call that method? Do you see the request being sent in the network tab?

Comment: I call it in a custom validator. When i use .subscribe  i Can see the response. The probleme are when i use .pipe(Map...